# Measuring current using test points

Tags: power

I understand that one can use the test points on the raspberry pi (model b) to test the voltage on the pi through a multimeter. Can the test points also be used to monitor the current on the board?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

You will need to put an ammeter in line with the power supply feed to measure the current flowing in to the Pi.